# Is there a type in the standard for storing the begin- and end-iterators of a container?

Tags: c++, iterator, std

My question is really simple: Is there a type in the standard whose purpose is to store the `begin`-terator and the `end`-iterator for a container?

I want to return both iterators from a single function. I'm aware I could use `std::pair` for this but it feels like there would be some type in the standard for this exact purpose. I've scanned the [<iterator>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iterator) header but can't seem to find a type like this. I'm not that good at iterator terminology so I'm not sure if one of those actually do what I'm looking for. Is there one that does?

(If you're interested in why I even want to do it in the first place, I have constant arrays in a class template that derives from a base class. Using polymorphism I want to iterate over their class constants, but I obviously can't have the virtual functions of the base class return the actual arrays since those are templated. Hence, I have virtual functions returning plain pointers, called `someArrayBegin()`, `someArrayEnd()`, `otherArrayBegin()`, etc, that I override in the derived class template to return the correct addresses.)

Comment: Unfortunately not, but there is C++20 `std::span` and of course ranges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a type in the standard for storing the begin- and end-iterators of a container?

Your description matches closely with the concept of a range.

`std::ranges::subrange` can be created from a pair of iterators. That will be templated based on the iterator type.

If you need to hide the iterator type for runtime polymorphism, you would need `ranges::any_view` which unfortunately isn't in the standard implementation of the ranges. Furthermore, there is a runtime cost associated with it.

For contiguous containers, another alternative is `std::span` which can point to any contiguous range without the cost of type erasure. For strings in particular, yet another alternative is `std::string_view`.

Comment: Well the containers in question are contiguous, so should I use `std::span` rather than `std::ranges::subrange`? Is there a reason to prefer one over the other?

Comment: @JensB Advantage of `std::ranges::subrange` is being generic, and the advantage of `std::span` is being specific. Good rule of thumb is to use more specific  when you don't need generic. The type of `std::ranges::subrange` is different for each iterator, while `std::span` is same for all contiguous containers, just like a plain pointer would be. That is useful when the contiguous containers may have different types.